# Karma test error after updating Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angular, karma-jasmine, visual-studio-code

This morning I ran my unit tests and everything worked as expected with some tests failing and several passing.  Then I updated Chrome to version 55 and suddenly I receive the error below, and none of my tests even run:

> WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:/

System configuration:

OS: Windows 10

IDE: VSCode 1.7.2

Karma 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below lines of code to make it work .

```
mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx']
    }
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2125